# I can't compare my login password with my registered password. Who can give me a solution to slove it?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

```
.model

.stack

.data

    fMenu DB 10,13,"************************************"
          DB 10,13,"*****   Welcome TO Our System  *****"
          DB 10,13,"*****  +---------------------+ *****"
          DB 10,13,"*****  |     1. Register     | *****"
          DB 10,13,"*****  |     2.  Login       | *****"
          DB 10,13,"*****  |     3.  Exit        | *****"
          DB 10,13,"*****  +---------------------+ *****"
          DB 10,13,"************************************"
          DB 10,13,"    Enter Your Selection : $"
    NUM1  DB ?
    ;MSG
    STR3 db 10,13,"Failed to register$"
    STR4 DB 10,13,"SUCCESS to REgister$"
    STR5 DB 10,13,"Not register yet.$"
    STR6 DB 10,13,"Password wrong.$"
    STR7 DB 10,13,"Login successfully.$"    
    ;-----user login and register msg
    STR1  DB 10,13,10,13,10,13,"*****LOGIN PAGE*****$"
    STR2  DB 10,13,10,13,10,13,"*****REGISTER PAGE*****$"
    USER  DB 10,13,"*****USERNAME : $"
    PASS  DB 10,13,"*****PASSWORD : $"
    ;user input
    RUSER DB 13 DUP(?) ;register user
    RPASS DB 10 DUP(?) ;register password
    CPASS DB 10 DUP(?) ;compare register password
    LUSER DB 13 DUP(?) ;login user
    LPASS DB 10 DUP(?) ;login password
.code

main proc

    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
Start:

    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, fMenu
    int 21h
    
    mov ah,01h ;let user prompt 1 number
    int 21h
    mov NUM1,al
    
    cmp NUM1,'1'
    JE REGISTER
    cmp NUM1,'2'
    JE HI
    cmp NUM1,'3'
    JE BYE
    
REGISTER:

    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,STR2
    int 21h 
    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,USER
    int 21h
    mov ah,3fh
    mov bx,0
    mov cx,13
    lea dx,RUSER
    int 21h
    CMP al,13
    JMP Dispass
BYE:

jmp exit

Hi:

jmp login

DisPass:

    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,Pass
    int 21h
    mov si,0
setpass:
    
    MOV AH,08H
    INT 21H
    CMP AL,0DH
    JE Comfirm
    MOV [RPASS+SI],AL
    MOV DL,'*'
    MOV AH,02H
    INT 21H
    INC SI
    Loop setpass

Comfirm:

    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,Pass
    int 21h

    mov si,0
DisC:

    MOV AH,08H
    INT 21H
    CMP AL,0DH
    JE compare
    MOV [CPASS+SI],AL
    MOV DL,'*'
    MOV AH,02H
    INT 21H
    INC SI

    JMP disc
    MOV BX,0
    mov cx,0
    
compare:

    mov al,RPASS[bx]
    inc bx
    cmp al,CPASS[bx-1]
    loope compare
    je success
    jne FAIl

LOGIN:

    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,STR1
    INT 21H
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,USER
    INT 21H
    mov ah, 3Fh
    MOV CX,13
    MOV BX,0                            
    lea dx, LUSER           
    int 21h 
    MOV CX,13
    MOV BX,0

    ;-----compare user input with register's input
    CHECKU:

        MOV AL,LUSER[BX]
        INC BX
        CMP AL,RUSER[BX-1]
        LOOPE CHECKU
    JE DIPAS
    JNE NOREG
DIPAS:

    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,Pass
    int 21h
    mov si,0
inpass:

    MOV BX,0
    mov cx,0
    MOV AH,08H
    INT 21H
    CMP AL,0DH
    JE CHECKP
    MOV [LPASS+SI],AL
    MOV DL,'*'
    MOV AH,02H
    INT 21H
    INC SI

    JMP INPASS

CHECKP:                 ;compare login password with register password

        MOV AL,LPASS[BX]    ;<------ i don't know got what problem
        INC BX
        CMP AL,RPASS[BX-1]
        LOOPE CHECKP
    JE LOSUCCESS
    JNE WroPa
FAIl:

    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,str3
    int 21h
    jmp Start
success:
        
    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,str4
    int 21h
    JMP LOGIN
NOREG:              ;not register yet

    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,str5
    int 21h
    jmp start
WroPa:              ;wrong password

    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,str6
    int 21h
    jmp LOGIN
LOSUCCESS:
    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,str7
    int 21h
exit:
 mov ah,4ch
 int 21h
main endp
end main
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license, for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CHECKP:                 ;compare login password with register password
>     MOV AL,LPASS[BX]    ;<------ i don't know got what problem
> ```

You knew how to verify the user name, then why would verifying the password be any different? You need to reset the `BX` register and load the `CX` register with the loop count.

---

> ```
> Loop setpass
> ```

This `Loop` instruction should become a `jmp` instruction!

---

> ```
>     mov cx,0
> compare:
> ```

The `CX` register here needs an initialization, say 10 because that's the length of the password buffers.

Comment: YES!! I found my problem! THANK!

Comment: @YINGWEICHAN: If this answer helps you, please do accept it by clicking on the (grey) arrow in the upper left corner of the answer.